# Codedeploy with AWS ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-code-deploy

I have configured an aws asg using ansible to provision new instances and then install the codedeploy agent via "user_data" script in a similar fashion as suggested in this question:

[Can I use AWS code Deploy for pulling application code while autoscaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903206/can-i-use-aws-code-deploy-for-pulling-application-code-while-autoscaling)

CodeDeploy works fine and I can install my application onto the asg once it has been created. When new instances are triggered in the ASG via one of my rules (e.g. high cpu usage), the codedeploy agent is installed correctly. The problem is, CodeDeploy does not install the application on these new instances. I suspect it is trying to run before the user_data script has finished. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Or know how to get CodeDeploy to automatically deploy the application to new instances which are spawned as part of the ASG?

Answer (score 0):

AutoScaling tells CodeDeploy to start the deployment before the user data is started. To get around this CodeDeploy gives the instance up to an hour to start polling for commands for the first lifecycle event instead of 5 minutes.

Since you are having problems with automatic deployments but not manual ones and assuming that you didn't make any manual changes to your instances you forgot about, there is most likely a dependency specific to your deployment that's not available yet at the time the instance launches.

Try listing out all the things that your deployment needs to succeed and make sure that each of those is available before you install the host agent. If you can log onto the instance fast enough (before AutoScaling terminates the instance), you can try and grab the host agent logs and your application's logs to find out where the deployment is failing.

If you think the host agent is failing to install entirely, make sure you have Ruby2.0 installed. It should be there by default on AmazonLinux, but Ubuntu and RHEL need to have it installed as part of the user data before you can install the host agent. There is an installer log in `/tmp` that you can check for problems in the initial install (again you have to be quick to grab the log before the instance terminates).